# Run Statistical Language Modeling (SLM) Toolkit on Linux terminal

Tags: speech-recognition

I installed The CMU Statistical Language Modeling (SLM) Toolkit v2 on Ubuntu
, but when I tried to run this

text2wfreq < transcription_file > data.wfreq

I had error which is the command not found, even though when I drag the execution file of the command to the terminal it worked

reading from standard input

how can I run it via this command text2wfreq < transcription_file > data.wfreq

and how can I make it read my text file by just drag it directly?

Comment: Make sure the directory it is in is in the path.  Or else specify the path to the executable when you run it.

Comment: Yes I am sure that my path is where my SLM tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux the commands you type are searched in PATH which is configured from environment variable. You need to set PATH environment variable to point to executables.

Current folder is not part of the PATH, so it does not matter where your current folder is. If you want to run command from the current folder you need to start with with "./"

```
./text2wfreq < transcription_file > data.wfreq
```

To learn more about Linux command line read a tutorial http://linuxcommand.org